# if I want to make new column based on the old columns range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a new column with old column's date range

```
df['block']= np.where((df['transacted_date']> '2016-06-01') & (df['transacted_date']< '2016-09-01') ,0,'None')
df['block']= np.where((df['transacted_date']> '2016-09-01') & (df['transacted_date']< '2016-12-01') ,1,'None')
```

is there way to do this in if elif statement?

Answer (score 1):

try using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
m1 = (df['transacted_date'] > '2016-06-01') & (df['transacted_date'] < '2016-09-01')


m2 = (df['transacted_date'] > '2016-09-01') &( df['transacted_date'] < '2016-12-01')

df['block'] = np.select(condlist=[m1,m2],
                        choicelist=[0,1],
                        default=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
m1 = df['transacted_date'].between('2016-06-01', '2016-09-01', inclusive = False)
m2 = df['transacted_date'].between('2016-09-01', '2016-12-01', inclusive = False)

df['block'] = np.select([m1,m2], [0,1], default=None)
```

If need `if-else` solution:

```
def f(x): 
    if (x > pd.Timestamp('2016-06-01')) and (x < pd.Timestamp('2016-09-01')): 
        return 0
    elif (x > pd.Timestamp('2016-09-01')) and (x < pd.Timestamp('2016-12-01')): 
        return 1
    else: 
        return None

df['block']=df['transacted_date'].apply(f)
```

If need more general solution use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), because `cut` cannot create `None` or `NaN` labels:

```
b = pd.to_datetime([pd.Timestamp.min,'2016-06-01','2016-09-01','2016-12-01',pd.Timestamp.max])

s = pd.cut(df['transacted_date'], bins=b, labels=[-2, 0, 1, -1])
df['block1'] = np.where(s.astype(int) >= 0, s, np.nan)
```